# How do you return an Iterator in Scala?

Tags: scala, iterator, traits

What must I do in order to be able to return an Iterator from a method/class ? How would one add that trait to a class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can extend [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Iterator.html), which will require that you implement the `next` and `hasNext` methods:

```
  class MyAnswer extends Iterator[Int] {
    def hasNext = true
    def next = 42
  }
```

But, you will get more flexibility if you extend [Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Iterable.html), which requires you implement `elements` (or `iterator` in 2.8):

```
  class MyAnswer extends Iterable[Int] {
    def iterator = new Iterator[Int] {
      def hasNext = true
      def next = 42
    }
  }
```

A common idiom seems to be to expose an iterator to some private collection, like this:

```
  class MyStooges extends Iterable[String] {
    private val stooges = List("Moe", "Larry", "Curly")
    def iterator = stooges.iterator
  }
```

Comment: There is't a way to send private messages but I'd like to pose a question: could you perhaps point me to a usage of the common idiom you mention? If not, what could it be useful for? Why not just return the List? Wouldn't this idiom be less efficient? (Also: I've seen that Iterable[A] "trick" a few times and it seems to  be one of the fastest ways to create something collection-like, are there any "alternatives" to this approach? I aks because Iterator gives little information so the methods can't be optimized well, what if I knew that my pseudo coll returns ordered or has fast random acces)

Answer (score 11):

For a method, just [yield](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111):

```
def odd(from: Int, to: Int): List[Int] = 
  for (i <- List.range(from, to) if i % 2 == 1) yield i
```

Comment: Correct, but...the code example doesn't actually answer the question. Just replace both instances of "List" with "Iterator" and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

These two answers had help from the posts below and thanks @Dima.

- [How do I implement an iterator for an existing singly linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44863398/5745234)
- [why does this iterable implementation produce a stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44889627/5745234)

Lets assume you have a class linked list. And the requirement is to print all the elements in the list.

```
trait LinkedList {
  def nodeValue: Int
  def tailList: LinkedList
}

class Node(val nodeValue: Int, val tailList: LinkedList) extends LinkedList

object Nil extends LinkedList {
  def nodeValue = throw new IllegalAccessException("head of Nil")
  def tailList = throw new IllegalAccessException("tail of Nil")
}

val singleLinkedList = new Node(1,Nil)
val chainedLinkedList = new Node(2,singleLinkedList)
print(chainedLinkedList)
A$A44$A$A44$Node@7b7a2c78res0: Unit = ()
```

Now Lets implement iterator to this class.

```
trait LinkedList extends Iterator[Int]{
  def nodeValue: Int
  def tailList: LinkedList
}

class Node(val nodeValue: Int, val tailList: LinkedList) extends LinkedList {
  var ptr: LinkedList = this

  //The following two are mandatory for extending Iterator
  override def hasNext: Boolean = ptr match { case Nil => false; case _=> true}

  override def next(): Int = {
    val result = ptr.nodeValue
    ptr = ptr.tailList
    result
  }
}

object Nil extends LinkedList {
  def nodeValue = throw new IllegalAccessException("head of Nil")
  def tailList = throw new IllegalAccessException("tail of Nil")

  //The following two are mandatory for extending Iterator
  override def hasNext: Boolean = false
  override def next(): Int = throw new IllegalAccessException("next of Nil")
}

val singleLinkedList = new Node(1,Nil)
val chainedLinkedList = new Node(2,singleLinkedList)

//Printing this first Time
chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
//Prints 2 1

//Printing second Time
chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
//No output
```

In the iterator implementation, once ptr reached the end, it could did not advance back. Iterable implementation solves this.

```
trait LinkedList extends Iterable[Int]{
  val nodeValue: Int
  val tailList: LinkedList
  override def toString(): String = this.mkString(" -> ")
}

class Node(val nodeValue: Int, val tailList: LinkedList) extends LinkedList {

  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator
    .iterate(this: LinkedList)(_.tailList)
    .takeWhile(_ != Nil)
    .map(_.nodeValue)
}

object Nil extends LinkedList {
  lazy val nodeValue= throw new IllegalAccessException("head of Nil")
  lazy val tailList = throw new IllegalAccessException("tail of Nil")

  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator.empty
}

val singleLinkedList = new Node(1,Nil)
val chainedLinkedList = new Node(2,singleLinkedList)

//Printing this first Time
chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
Output 2 -> 1
chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
Output 2 -> 1
```