# How would I wrap a Scanner instance such that I get a stream of doubles I can .fold() on without reading everyting in memory?

Tags: scala

I would like to process a text file containing floating point values separated by whitespace (incl. newlines); I'd like to be able to work on arbitrarily large input, so `Source.fromFile(...).mkString` is out of question. I assume it should be relatively straightforward to wrap a `java.util.Scanner` instance into a stream of doubles that calls `.nextDouble()` on the `Scanner` every time the next value is requested. This way I could efficiently reduce the stream without resorting to an imperative approach. I'm thinking of something in the lines of:

```
val in = new Scanner(...)
val reducedData = wrapScanner(in).fold(...)
```

P.S. not sure if "stream" is the right term here, but I'm definitely not referring to Scala Streams specifically.

P.P.S. I'm aware of the existence of `Iterator/Stream.continually` but I don't know how to tell it where to stop (so as to avoid a `NoSuchElementException` at the end of the file).

Comment: those values are all on one line?

Comment: No, but that doesn't matter when using a `java.util.Scanner`—they are whitespace/newline separated.

Comment: I asked, because if every value on it's own line you could use `Source.fromFile(...).getLines.fold(...)` and process lines lazily, one by one.

Comment: I see—but yeah, they're not; otherwise I would have been satisfied with `.getLines` :)

Comment: well you only mentioned `fromFile(...).mkString` which loads whole file as one big chunk.

Comment: I've made the question unambiguous in that regard. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally in plain Java you'd just create an `Iterator` containing the `Scanner`, and connect `hasNext()` and `next()` methods to the `Scanner` `readDouble()`.

```
public class ScanDoubles_Iterator implements Iterator<Double> {
    protected Scanner scanner;
    public boolean hasNext() { return scanner.hasNextDouble(); }
    public Double next() { return scanner.nextDouble(); }
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
};
```

Let's copy some Scala examples:

```
class ScanDoubles_Iterator extends Iterator[Double] {
    val scanner: Scanner = /* init from a constructor */
    def hasNext = scanner.hasNextDouble()
    def next = scanner.nextDouble()
}
```

This is adapted from a Scala example of implementing a (Scala I assume) `Iterator`. See [How do you return an Iterator in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135462/how-do-you-return-an-iterator-in-scala)

Comment: The end *is* defined, but what I don't know is how to tell `Iterator` to make use of `hasNext` (without resorting to the slightly longer approach in the answer I've provided).

Comment: OK, perfect; and that can in turn be reduced to: `val in = new Scanner(...); val it = new Iterator[Double] { def hasNext = in.hasNextDouble; def next = in.nextDouble }`!

Answer (score 0):

Based on guidance from @om-nom-nom, I've come up with the following solution:

```
val in = new java.util.Scanner(...)
val doubles = Iterator
  .continually(if (in.hasNextDouble) Some(in.nextDouble) else None)
  .takeWhile(_ != None)
  .map(_.get)
val sum = doubles.reduce(_ + _)
```

...but I'm not particularly happy about the fiddling around with the stream; I'd be really happy to accept a cleaner solution as the answer.

**Update**: looks like Thomas W has found a good solution; I'm gonna post it here for completeness' sake:

```
val in = new Scanner(file)
val it = new Iterator[Double] { def hasNext = in.hasNextDouble; def next = in.nextDouble }
val sum = it.foldLeft(_ + _)
```