# How do I implement an iterator for an existing singly linked list?

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement an iterable for this singly linked list using dependency injection. I am expecting hasNext to return true and next() to return the first element. But it errors out. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
// Definition for singly-linked list from codefights:
class ListNode[T](x : T) {
  var value: T = x
  var next: Option[ListNode[T]] = None
}
//This class will provide iterator for the above list.    
implicit class ln(lns: Option[ListNode[Int]]) extends Iterable[Option[ListNode[Int]]] {

  var ptr = lns  //temporary variable to store the state of iterator

  override def iterator = new Iterator[Option[ListNode[Int]]] {
    //if the current node pointed to is None, there are no elements.
    override def hasNext = ptr match {case None=> false; case _ => true}

    //store the current ptr to temp variable and return it.
    override def next = { var tmp = ptr; ptr = ptr.get.next; tmp }
  }

  //defined +: to perform tests
  def +:(that: Option[ListNode[Int]]) = that match {
    case None => lns
    case _ => that.get.next = lns; that
  }


}

//create 3 nodes that will be linked in next step
var a = new ListNode(1)
var b = new ListNode(2)
var c = new ListNode(3)


//link the 3 nodes
val xx : Option[ListNode[Int]]= Some(c) +: Some(b) +: Some(a)

//I know this is not dependency injection. But I wanted to debug the issue.
val ax: ln = new ln(xx)
//ax.size

//checking the iterator manually
ax.iterator.hasNext
ax.iterator.next()

Output:

> defined class ListNode
> defined class ln
> a: ListNode[Int] = ListNode@79c41e43 b: ListNode[Int] =
> ListNode@5fbdb591 c: ListNode[Int] = ListNode@a8e723
> 
> xx: Option[ListNode[Int]] = Some(A$A131$A$A131$ListNode@a8e723)
> 
> ax: ln = A.A131.A.A131(Some(A$A131$A$A131$ListNode@a8e723),
> Some(A$A131$A$A131$ListNode@5fbdb591),
> Some(A$A131$A$A131$ListNode@79c41e43))
> 
> res0: Boolean = false java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get  at
> scala.None$.get(palindrom.sc:345)     at
> scala.None$.get(palindrom.sc:343)     at
> #worksheet#.ln$$anon$1.next(palindrom.sc:23)  at 

#worksheet#.ln$$anon$1.next(palindrom.sc:20)    at #worksheet#.get$$instance$$res1(palindrom.sc:39)     at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(palindrom.sc:84)
```

Update:
I am not allowed to modify class ListNode. Which I did not mention before. My mistake. I just added toString below for clear printing though.

But I modified the rest of the code based on @Dima suggestion. I am wowed!! Because, I can just use map like a regular list. Thanks a lot!!

```
class ListNode[T](x : T) {
  var value: T = x
  var next: Option[ListNode[T]] = None
  override def toString = x.toString
}



implicit class ln(val lns: ListNode[Int]) extends  Iterable[Int] {

  override def iterator = Iterator.iterate(Option(lns))(_.flatMap(_.next))
    .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
    .flatten
    .map(_.value)

  def +:(that: Int) : ListNode[Int] = {
    val newNode = new ListNode(that)
      newNode.next = Some(lns)
      newNode}


}


val xx : ListNode[Int]= 1 +: 2 +: new ListNode(3)

xx.foreach(println)

xx.map( _ +1)
```

> Output
>
> xx: ListNode[Int] = 1
>
> res0: Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. Just don't. I am sorry, I started typing several times trying to explain what's wrong with it, but I can't ... it's *all* wrong.

Back to the drawing board.
First of all, scrap the mutable state. You don't need it. For now, just pretend, that there is no `var` in scala.

```
case class ListNode[T](value: T, next: Option[ListNode[T]] = None) {
   def +:(head: T) = ListNode(head, Some(this))
}
```

Now. It seems weird, that your iterator is iterating over `Option[ListNode[T]]` rather than `T`, or, at least, `ListNode[T]`. 
Wrapping it into `Option` seems completely useless. 
This iterates over `T`, because it seems the most sensible, if you want `ListNode[T]` instead, remove the last `.map`. 
If you insist on `Option[ListNode[T]]`, remove both `.map` and `.flatten`.

```
object ListNode {
   implicit class Iterable[T](val node: ListNode[T]) extends AnyVal {
      def iterator = Iterator
         .iterate(Option(node))(_.flatMap(_.next))
         .takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)
         .flatten
         .map(_.value)
   }
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
 (1 +: 2 +: ListNode(3))
   .iterator
   .toList // returns List(1,2,3)
```

This is it. If you are going to write code in scala, you might as well take a few minutes to learn how the language is intended to be used. You'll grow to appreciate it.