# why does this iterable implementation produce a stackoverflow?

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement an iterable for a linked list. But this implementation throws stack overflow error. What am I doing wrong here?

The iterable implementation throws error, even before I call any function on the class.

I initially thought, it could be because of using def instead of val for the nodeValue and tailList. But that didnt solve the problem.

I tried to change the iterator to loop over Int instead of LinkedList. I still get the same error.
Thanks in advance!!

```
trait LinkedList extends Iterable[LinkedList]{
  def nodeValue: Int
  def tailList: LinkedList
}

class Node(val nodeValue: Int, val tailList: LinkedList) extends LinkedList {

  override def iterator: Iterator[LinkedList] = Iterator
    .iterate(this: LinkedList)(_.tailList)
    .takeWhile(_ != Nil)
}

object Nil extends LinkedList {
  def nodeValue= throw new IllegalAccessException("head of Nil")
  def tailList = throw new IllegalAccessException("tail of Nil")

  override def iterator: Iterator[LinkedList] = Iterator.empty
}

val singleLinkedList = new Node(1,Nil)
val chainedLinkedList = new Node(2,singleLinkedList)

//Printing this first Time
//chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
```

> Output:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:50)
    at scala.collection.AbstractSeq.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:37)
    at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSeq.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:44)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:28)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:45)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.<init>(LinkedListIterable.sc:50)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.mkString(LinkedListIterable.sc:319)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.mkString$(LinkedListIterable.sc:318)
    at #worksheet#.Node.mkString(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.toString(LinkedListIterable.sc:596)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.toString$(LinkedListIterable.sc:596)
    at #worksheet#.Node.toString(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(LinkedListIterable.sc:2990)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(LinkedListIterable.sc:196)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$addString$1(LinkedListIterable.sc:355)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(LinkedListIterable.sc:925)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(LinkedListIterable.sc:925)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(LinkedListIterable.sc:1413)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(LinkedListIterable.sc:67)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(LinkedListIterable.sc:66)
    at #worksheet#.Node.foreach(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.addString(LinkedListIterable.sc:353)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.addString$(LinkedListIterable.sc:349)
    at #worksheet#.Node.addString(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.mkString(LinkedListIterable.sc:319)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.mkString$(LinkedListIterable.sc:318)
    at #worksheet#.Node.mkString(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.toString(LinkedListIterable.sc:596)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.toString$(LinkedListIterable.sc:596)
    at #worksheet#.Node.toString(LinkedListIterable.sc:6)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(LinkedListIterable.sc:2990)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(LinkedListIterable.sc:196)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$addString$1(LinkedListIterable.sc:355)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(LinkedListIterable.sc:925)
Output exceeds cutoff limit.
```

> Update:

The problem is as mentioned by @Dima, Iterator, iterates through some value in container and not the container itself. Once that was clear, I modified the code, which ran fine as below.

```
trait LinkedList extends Iterable[Int]{
  val nodeValue: Int
  val tailList: LinkedList
  override def toString(): String = this.mkString(" -> ")
}

class Node(val nodeValue: Int, val tailList: LinkedList) extends LinkedList {

  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator
    .iterate(this: LinkedList)(_.tailList)
    .takeWhile(_ != Nil)
    .map(_.nodeValue)
}

object Nil extends LinkedList {
  lazy val nodeValue= throw new IllegalAccessException("head of Nil")
  lazy val tailList = throw new IllegalAccessException("tail of Nil")

  override def iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator.empty
}

val singleLinkedList = new Node(1,Nil)
val chainedLinkedList = new Node(2,singleLinkedList)

//Printing this first Time
chainedLinkedList.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is, that normally `Iterable.iterator` iterates over the *values* in the container, not the actual container nodes.

What happens here, is when you type `new Node(1, Nil)` in REPL, it tries to print out the result, and calls `Node.toString`, which is implemented on `Iterable` to iterate through the entire container, and convert all values to string.

So, it calls your `iterator`, gets the `next` (what it thinks is) element, and tries to convert it to a String. But what your `iterator` returns isn't the value stored in the node, but the node itself, so, when `toString` is called on it, it is still the same `Iterable.toString`, that ends up calling the same `iterator`, that'll return the same node, that it'll try to convert to string ... etc. Infinite recursion.

Comment: Lesson learnt. First line summarizes everything. I updated it to iterate on Int and everything looks fine.